# how to add more than one dimension table while creating a materialized view in Azure Data Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, materialized-views

I am trying to create a materialized view with 2 dimension tables, but getting error with the below syntax,

```
.create async materialized-view with (backfill=true, dimensionTables = 'SalesUserTable','ProductTable') SalesSummary on table PurchaseTable
{
PurchaseTable | join kind = inner SalesUserTable on $left.SalesUserId == $right.SalesUserID
| join kind = inner ProductTable on $left.ProductID == $right.ProductID
| extend TotalPrice = (Quantity*Price)
| summarize
TotalQuantity = sum(Quantity),
TotalPrice = sum(TotalPrice)
by SalesUserId, ProductID, SalesUserName=Name, ProductName=Name1
}
```

Please help me with the right syntax to add multiple dimension table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put table names in a **single** set of quotes:

```
.create async materialized-view with (backfill=true, dimensionTables = 'SalesUserTable, ProductTable') SalesSummary on table PurchaseTable
```